# Как сделать кликабельными объекты на изображении?

Tags: java, android, graphics, карты, 2d

Суть проблемы такова: есть карта, на которой размещены объекты (изображение в виде карты). Нужно, чтоб при нажатии на объект открывалась новая `Activity`, с подробной информацией о нём.

С помощью чего можно сделать эти объекты на изображении кликабельными?

Есть ли, возможно, уже готовые библиотеки, или какой-либо материал, где хорошо объяснено, как это сделать?

Comment: карта уже есть, и это картинка? или карту еще предстоит создать?

Comment: @tse Да, у меня будет план рынка в виде картинки. там будут отрисованы объекты. Вот надо сделать те объекты кликабельными. я так понимаю,  это придется высчитывать зоны для объектов и проверять их попиксельно. Но вот хотя-бы пример, какой-никакой был.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете перехватить событие касания у элемента с картинкой:

```
    mapImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // do something
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Дальше определяйте объект по координатам.

Comment: спасибо, попробую. Есть ли статью вообще по работе с картами? язык: русский или английски

Comment: в смысле с картами? как создать свою карту? не знаю. как использовать google или yandex map? куча, спросите гугла, одна другой краше.

Comment: в общем спасибо. я именно про создать свою. буду искать